# Why does my api post request (Vue.js client) receive an undefined response from my express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, fetch

My client is Vue.js using a Vuex store. I am using passport.js for authentication on the server side. Login and account registration is working. Checking mongodb shows new data. But express is sending an undefined response to the client. This is my first major javascript project so I'm hoping it's something simple my eyes just can't see yet.

client: api.js

```
export async function registerUser(user) {
  console.log("api to register user");
  console.log(user);
  const route = `${api}/register`;
  return fetch(route, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.json());
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      return json;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

client: index.js (vuex store where res is undefined)

```
actions: {
async register(state, user) {
      apis.registerUser(user).then(res => {
        if (res.success) {
          this.dispatch("loadUser");
          alert("successfully registered");
        }
      });
    },
    async loadUser() {
      apis.getUser().then(res => {
        this.commit("setUser", res.user);
      });
    }
}
```

server: app.js

```
app.post('/api/v1/register', function(req, res) { 
  const success = true;
  Users=new User({email: req.body.email, username : req.body.username}); 
  console.log(req.body);
  User.register(Users, req.body.password, function(err, user) { 
    if (err) { 
      console.log('account could not be saved');
      success = false;
    } else { 
      console.log('account saved');
    }
  })
  res.send({success: success});
});
```

fetch error printing to console

[image]

The server console.logs in the app.js route indicate the req.body has the right data and user account is saved successfully. No errors occur on res.send but the client gets an undefined response.

Comment: Does the console.log works from your api.js ? It seems you have a network error. Check that the `api` variable is something like `/api/v1`

Comment: make sure your `const route = \`${api}/register\`;` is actually have the right url as you defined in server `/api/v1/register`. At first, try hardcoding the url. You can also inspect the network request in chrome (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network)

Comment: The url is correct. It is hitting the server. Console screenshot above is what I'm getting from the client fetch.

Answer (score 0):

After much banging my head against the table and some outside assistance, I found a solution. I had two main issues.

1. I was not preventing the default on the submit button so the form was refreshing before the request was properly handled.
2. Mishandling of javascript promises.

Working code below:

api.js

```
export function registerUser(user) {
  console.log("api to register user");
  console.log(user);
  const route = `${api}/register`;
  return fetch(route, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.json());
      return response.json();
    })
}
```

index.js (vuex store)

```
actions: {
register(state, user) {
      apis.registerUser(user).then(res => {
        if (res.success) {
          alert("successfully registered");
        }
      }).catch(err => {
          console.error(err);
      });
    }
}
```

app.js code remained the same